# QStandardItem redefinition error

Tags: c++, qt, qstandarditem

I am trying to make a model using `QStandardItemModel` in Qt. I have done it in the following two ways. In the second method I just expanded the loop, and I get `redefinition of 'item'` error, while the first method works fine.

- method 1

  ```
  QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel( 3, 1 );
  QStringList modelStepsTags = {"item-1","item-2","item-3"};
  for( int r=0; r<3; r=r+1 )
  {
      QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem( modelStepsTags.at(r) );
      model->setItem(r, 0, item);
  }
  ```
- method 2

  ```
  QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel( 3, 1 );
  QStringList modelStepsTags = {"item-1","item-2","item-3"};
  QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem( modelStepsTags.at(0) );
  model->setItem(0, 0, item);
  QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem( modelStepsTags.at(1) );
  model->setItem(1, 0, item);
  QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem( modelStepsTags.at(2) );
  model->setItem(2, 0, item);
  ```

Comment: `QStandardItem *item` more than once in the same scope is the definition of redefinition. Change the second and subsequent  `QStandardItem *item`s into `item` to reruse the first definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item is defined three times.

```
QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel( 3, 1 );
QStringList modelStepsTags = {"item-1","item-2","item-3"};
QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem( modelStepsTags.at(0) ); // here
model->setItem(0, 0, item);
QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem( modelStepsTags.at(1) ); // here
model->setItem(1, 0, item);
QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem( modelStepsTags.at(2) ); // and here
model->setItem(2, 0, item);
```

You can get away with reusing the first definition

```
QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel( 3, 1 );
QStringList modelStepsTags = {"item-1","item-2","item-3"};
QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem( modelStepsTags.at(0) );
model->setItem(0, 0, item);
item = new QStandardItem( modelStepsTags.at(1) ); // reuse
model->setItem(1, 0, item);
item = new QStandardItem( modelStepsTags.at(2) ); // reuse
model->setItem(2, 0, item);
```

Or discard the variable entirely as it is redundant

```
QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel( 3, 1 );
QStringList modelStepsTags = {"item-1","item-2","item-3"};
model->setItem(0, 0, new QStandardItem( modelStepsTags.at(0) ));
model->setItem(1, 0, new QStandardItem( modelStepsTags.at(1) ));
model->setItem(2, 0, new QStandardItem( modelStepsTags.at(2) ));
```